# Context implementation

Tags: android

Where can I see the implementation of this class?

I've looked in the internal packages of Android on [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.3_r1) but haven't found it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The class to search for is `android.app.ContextImpl`.

See ContextImpl for Android 4.0.4 [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.4_r2.1/android/app/ContextImpl.java#ContextImpl) or version overview [here](http://grepcode.com/search?query=android.app.ContextImpl%20&start=0&entity=type&n=).

Answer (score 4):

Here: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/Context.java

Comment: No, Michael, it's just abstract class but I searching for implementation, another words I want to see how Context's methods works.

Comment: @Ivan It's really hard to follow your sentences. Please use correct spelling and grammer and keep a good style. So, I still can't say what you are searching for exactly. ContextWrapper extends Context. Activity extends ContextWrapper. Maybe Activity is what you are searching - a well working `implementation` of Context.

Comment: sorry for my bad English. But I try to explain what I need, ContextWrapper(and Activity) it's classes just used contract of context, they do not provide behaviour of Context. Please look at ContextWrapper's [startActivity()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/content/ContextWrapper.java#ContextWrapper.startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29) method. It uses mBase object, it's implementation of Context. And instance to mBase assigns in constructor.
Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Im still not sure what's the actual problem. `Context` does provide an [empty implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/content/Context.java#Context.startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29) of the `startActivity` method, just ready to be overriden. :)